# Cannot connect to .sock file

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix-socket

> 'Error: connect ENOENT unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock\n    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:860:11)\n    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:883:20)\n    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)'

When I am connecting to my server, which requests PHP file from second server then error happens.

Sock file exists but PHP server fails to connect to it using net.Stream.

How can I fix this problem?

```
var connection = new net.Stream();
...
connection.connect(options.fastcgiHost);
```

Comment: `/run/php-fpm/...` looks like an invalid path, shouldn't that be `/var/run/php-fpm/...`?

Comment: No, path is valid (ls /run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock works and /run is just /run).

Comment: What is `net.Stream()` exactly? I thought that it was called [`net.connect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_path_connectlistener).

Comment: Even when using `var connection = net.connect({path:options.fastcgiHost});` instead of previous code it's not working. Same error.

Comment: When path is without unix: it's returning hang up. In finality I will use C module.